# Filtered most_common() for Counter in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, counter

I have a counter formatted as {(f1, f2): counts}.  When I run the Counter.most_common() on this I get correct results but I want to filter most_common() for some filter on f2. For example f2 = 'A' should return most_common elements having f2 = 'A'.  How to do this?

Comment: On mobile so can't be sure but try `sorted([item for item in counter.items() if item[0][1]=='A'], key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)[:10]`

Comment: @roippi It worked.  If you fill in an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at the source code for `Counter` we see that it uses `heapq` to remain `O(n + k log n)` where `k` is the number of keys wanted and `n` is the size of the `Counter`, as opposed to `O(n log n)`.

```
def most_common(self, n=None):
    '''List the n most common elements and their counts from the most
    common to the least.  If n is None, then list all element counts.

    >>> Counter('abcdeabcdabcaba').most_common(3)
    [('a', 5), ('b', 4), ('c', 3)]

    '''
    # Emulate Bag.sortedByCount from Smalltalk
    if n is None:
        return sorted(self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return _heapq.nlargest(n, self.items(), key=_itemgetter(1))
```

Because this is more than `O(n)`, we can just filter the counter and get its items:

```
counts = Counter([(1, "A"), (2, "A"), (1, "A"), (2, "B"), (1, "B")])

Counter({(f1, f2): n for (f1, f2), n in counts.items() if f2 == "A"}).most_common(2)
#>>> [((1, 'A'), 2), ((2, 'A'), 1)]
```

Although unwrapping it may make it slightly faster, if that matters:

```
import heapq
from operator import itemgetter

filtered = [((f1, f2), n) for (f1, f2), n in counts.items() if f2 == "A"]
heapq.nlargest(2, filtered, key=itemgetter(1))
#>>> [((1, 'A'), 2), ((2, 'A'), 1)]
```